# Can't use is_home in template-functions.php

Tags: widgets, homepage

I'm trying to load a slider in my header, but only on the homepage.

I'm using The Ultralight template if that helps.

I'm trying to (in template-functions.php) do the following:

```
<?php if ( is_page( 'home' ) ) : ?>
            dynamic_sidebar( 'Homepage Widget' ); 
        <?php endif; ?>
```

But this doesn't work. Now from a quick google, it seems I need to enqueue the request, but when I try this, I get a syntax error:

```
<?php
        add_action( 'wp', 'wpse47305_check_home' );
        function wpse47305_check_home() {
            if ( is_home() )
                add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
        }

        function my_scripts() {
         dynamic_sidebar( 'Homepage Widget' ); 
        }
        ?>
```

Edit: So this doesn't seemingly add my sidebar in where I was expecting it to load in. I presume i've misunderstood the concept here.

Comment: `if( is_home() || is_front_page() )` might be helpful. Because by default `is_home()` detects the blog page. And I don't think, enqueuing is necessary here. If the problem is specific to the Ultralight theme, then I'm afraid, the question would be off-topic here.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up a few things. `dynamic_sidebar()` goes into the _template itself_, wherever you want it to appear. If it's in the header, then that would be header.php (probably, it depends on the theme). But to use dynamic sidebar you first need to register it so that you can put widgets in it. Use `register_sidebar()` to do that. See [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_sidebar/#comment-366) for an example. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with scripts here. How are you trying to add this slider, is it a widget?

Comment: solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested yet but try using this, $url =  "//{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}"; if is same as "example.com"

Comment: I've tried is_front_page, is_home and is_page ('home') and none of them work. 

It seems that at the point template-functions is loading, php doesn't know what page is loaded in yet, so it is something to do with script enqueuing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as @Jacob Peattie mentioned, I had got myself confused. I needed to put this in my header.php rather than in the template-functions.php